# How to differentiate the hinge loss?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, calculus, hinge-loss

I'm asked to differentiate the following hinge loss term.
$$ \dfrac{1}{n}\sum _{\left( x_{i},y_{1}\right) \in S}\sum _{j'=1}L\left( w^{j'};\left( x_{i},y_{i}\right) \right) $$

where
$$
L\left( w^{j'};\left( x_{i},y_{i}\right) \right) = ( \max \{ 0,2-\left( \langle w^{j'},x_{i}\rangle \right) 1\{ y_{i}= j'\} ) ^{2}
$$

The one function is = 1 when $y_i = j'$ and 0 otherwise.
I need the partial derivative along $w^j_k$. I also have the following assumption to help me :
$$\dfrac{\partial }{\partial a}\max \left\{ 0,a\right\} =\begin{cases} 1 \quad \text{if} \quad a >0\\ 0 \quad \text{if} \quad a\leq 0\end{cases}$$
*I know that this assumption not really true but just consider it as true in my case.*

My problem is that I have no clue how to differentiate this and I need this to compute the gradient for my SVM model.

Comment: Your formula for the derivative is not fully correct: it is not defined for $a=0.$  That's more than a technical nitpick: this failure to be differentiable everywhere leads to failure of certain optimization algorithms, for instance.

Comment: I know that the assumption is not really true but I'm required to use it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, in mathematics when you adopt a known false assumption you may immediately conclude literally anything you like ;-).  It sounds like you are expected to conduct an exercise in applying the Chain Rule of Calculus.

Comment: I have trouble seeing how to derivate elements of a matrix do we get a sum of x because w derivate to 1 when doing the dot product between w and x?

Comment: Because derivatives of the $w^j$ with respect to the $w^{j^\prime}$ are either $0$ or $1,$ that makes your work easy.  The multivariate Chain Rule is stated at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case.

Comment: So if w_j = w_j' the derivative is 1 otherwise it's 0? But what is w_j' ? Is it a specific value?